# Error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required

Tags: generics, rust

Apologies for the generic title.

Here is some example code:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

pub trait Bar<A: Foo> {
    fn bar(&self, a: A);
}

pub struct Test<A, B>
    where A: Foo,
          B: Bar<A>
{
    _phantom_r: PhantomData<A>,
    bars: Vec<B>,
}

impl<A, B> Test<A, B>
    where A: Foo,
          B: Bar<A>
{
    pub fn new() -> Test<A, B> {
        Test {
            _phantom_r: PhantomData,
            bars: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_bar(&mut self, b: B) {
        self.bars.push(b);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t = Test::new();
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=989824eb1e4d1a594eebab1b421dc987&version=stable&backtrace=0))

The error is:

```
<anon>:32:13: 36:22 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
<anon>:32     let t = Test::new();
```

I'm quite confused on what Rust is having trouble inferring the trait types, and how I can specify what it wants. That is, I'm not sure if this is right, because then I run into `Sized` issues:

```
let t = Test::new() as Test<Foo,Bar<Foo>>;
```

error:

```
<anon>:36:28: 36:46 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Foo` [E0277]
<anon>:36     let t = Test::new() as Test<Foo,Bar<Foo>>;
```

I have two main questions:

1. Why is Rust unable to infer the trait types of `Test<A,B<A>>`?
2. What is the solution to make this code work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you haven't told it what type to use.

Paraphrasing your declarations:

```
pub trait Foo {}
```

"There is a trait `Foo`"

```
pub trait Bar<A: Foo> {}
```

"If you give me a type `A` which implements `Foo`, I can give you a trait `Bar<A>`."

```
pub struct Test<A, B>
    where A: Foo,
          B: Bar<A> {}
```

"If you give me types `A`, which implements `Foo`, and `B`, which implements `Bar<A>`, I'll give you a type `Test<A,B>`.

```
let t = Test::new();
```

"Make me a `Test`".  This is the problem - `Test` isn't a type, it's a template for making a type given two other types (with some restrictions).  In the example above you haven't provided any such types, just narrowed down what such types might be like.

To actually use `Test`, you need to provide the types:

```
struct MyA {}
impl Foo for MyA {
    fn foo(&self) { println!("MyA::foo"); }
}

struct MyB {}
impl Bar<MyA> for MyB {
    fn bar(&self, a: MyA) { println!("MyB::bar"); }

}

fn main() {
    let test = Test::<MyA, MyB>::new();
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c3c7ccc8f54daa8340e09490a195249d&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Comment: Nice answer. Another thing is that the compilers' inference reach is quite high - so you could potentially omit the type parameters if your code satisfied the inference mechanisms.. via using `add_foo` and `add_bar` methods, like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c507bbcd0ad94bfa892c09e097354b5b&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! My biggest question in response to Chris, was exactly what you brought up Simon! My issue was that i cannot provide concrete types like in Chris' example - IE: `MyA` and `MyB` structs. I'm using traits *because* i don't have a specific, concrete type - i have multiple types that i'm adding, like in Simon's example.

Comment: With that said, maybe i'm designing this wrong. Is it not possible to accept multiple concrete types that implement the same interface in a single function? Ie, [play example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0b350bc006fee6528b28c1720ae75180&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Both `MyB` and `MyC` implement `Foo`, and `Test::add_bar()` implements accepts a `B<Foo>`, yet it appears that `add_bar()` is only accepting a single concrete type, rather than traits over the type. Thoughts? Perhaps i fundamentally misunderstand Rust's implementation of Traits (i was thinking of them more like Go interfaces)

Comment: @FizzBazer perhaps you want a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html)?

Comment: @Shepmaster Seems so, thanks! For anyone else, i think i figured out a problem with the design. Static Dispatch works by creating alternate, type specific methods - but this is incompatible for a Vector. If you're going to store them in a data structure (i imagine vector, hashmap, etcetc) it cannot be duplicated at compile time via Static Dispatch. So, if you use a Vector, Dynamic Dispatch is apparently required. I have yet to use Dynamic Dispatch, so a' learning i must go. Thanks all!

Comment: I summarized my findings regarding vectors and static dispatch here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37419935/6189743

Answer (score 0):

You can boil the first error down to this:

```
fn main() {
    let v = Vec::new();
}
```

The problem here is that the compiler has no way to determine what the concrete type will be contained by the vector. In your case, you create a structure (`Test`) that can be created without passing in concrete types for `A` and `B`, but the underlying reasoning is the same.

The second issue is related. Neither `Foo` nor `Bar` are concrete types with a size known at compile time. Trying to use them in a location that requires a fixed size (represented by the `Sized` trait) will fail.

When you instantiate a type, the size of the type **must** be known and that's done by providing concrete types in place of the generic type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A note about the accepted answer - The accepted answer covers the problem with identifying traits, however there are some comments within that thread that explain additional details with this question. I'm summarizing one of them here for ease of reading (since comments are a bit hard to read).

[Static Dispatch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html#static-dispatch) *(which is used when you us a Trait like in the above code)* will not work with multiple concrete types on a vector.

For example, take this example:

```
trait Foo {
    fn method(&self) -> String;
}
impl Foo for u8 {
    fn method(&self) -> String {
        format!("u8: {}", *self)
    }
}

impl Foo for String {
    fn method(&self) -> String {
        format!("string: {}", *self)
    }
}

struct Test<T: Foo> {
    foos: Vec<T>,
}
impl<T:Foo> Test<T> {
    pub fn do_something(&self, x: T) {
        self.foos.push(x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5u8;
    let y = "Hello".to_string();

    let t = Test {foos:Vec::new()};
    t.do_something(x);
    t.do_something(y);
}
```

This will **not** work, because while `do_something()` *could* use Static Dispatch, `Test::foos` *cannot*. If we instead changed `Test` to:

```
struct Test {
}
impl Test {
    pub fn do_something<T: Foo>(&self, x: T) {
        x.method();
    }
}
```

It will work. The `main()` function did not need to change at all *(aside from removing the vector)*, it entirely had to do with the Vector causing static dispatch *(apparently)* to not work.

In this case, i believe [Dynamic Dispatch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html#dynamic-dispatch) will work - but i'm not familiar enough with it just yet to give any in depth answer/example here. Hope this helps future readers.